# Pruning not working In find

Tags: text-processing, rhel, find, text-formatting

```
find . \( -type f  \) -o \( -name "*.rpm"   -prune \)

find . \( -name "*.sh" \) -o \( -name "*.rpm"  -prune \)
```

The second command excludes .rpm but the first one doesn't.
What's the problem with first one?
Os:: Rhel 6(Redhat Enterprise Linux 6)

Comment: There is no problem with the first one. It just prints out a list of files, the -o part is never executed unless you have directories or links ending in `.rpm`.

Comment: ! Just negates the .rpm  that's fine but is there any alternative for -o so that the -prune also gets executed

Comment: I only use pruning in `find` on directories, so you don't recurse in the branches (= subdirectories) underneath. WIth find anding is implicit, `-o` has to be given explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first command matches all files it never comes to pruning `.rpm` files. Try:

```
find .  -type f  ! -name "*.rpm"
```